# How to compile table of contents correctly in Abstract Book using JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm working on report of type Abstract Book. It includes ToC(table of contents) and subreport (JRXML):

```
    <group name="cover">
            <groupHeader>
                <part evaluationTime="Report" uuid="56ab525c-754f-4f48-a52c-7cc23934be3d">
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.bookmarks.data.source.parameter" value="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE"/>
                    <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts"
                                     xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                        <subreportParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                            <subreportParameterExpression>
                                <![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("combinedReport")]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                        </subreportParameter>
                        <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{tocReport}]]></subreportExpression>
                    </p:subreportPart>
                </part>
            </groupHeader>
        </group>
<detail>
        <part uuid="9431bc63-c820-403c-a317-e7ffe3295dcf">
            <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts"
                             xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                <subreportParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                    <subreportParameterExpression>
                        <![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("combinedReport")]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{subreport}]]></subreportExpression>
            </p:subreportPart>
        </part>
    </detail>
```

I've added a hyperlink to the textfield in the subreport:

```
<textField textAdjust="StretchHeight" hyperlinkType="LocalAnchor" bookmarkLevel="1">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="280" height="30" uuid="8a8b1b38-78d3-4ab5-a728-6c0f2796371d"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Bla bla"]]></textFieldExpression>
                <anchorNameExpression><![CDATA["Bla bla"]]></anchorNameExpression>
            </textField>
```

However the table of contents is empty, only shows the static text "Table of contents" on the top of the page.
Here is the way I compile the report (short version):

```
 subReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxmlContentOutputPath);
 tocReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxmlTocOutputPath);
InputStream templateIs = ReportPdfService.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jasper-reports/Abstract_Book.jrxml");
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("REPORT_DATA_SOURCE", jsonDataSource);
parameters.put("subreport", subReport);
parameters.put("tocReport", tocReport);
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(templateIs);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, outputReportPdfPath);
```

I think the problem is hyperlink which is created after toc is compiled or something. But nothing works.

Comment: I think evaluationTime="Report" doesn't work or something

Comment: Is it possibile to  have a [MCVE], hence something that I can copy and past into my IDE to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with detail band, which has parameter splitType="Immediate". When I removed it, ToC started working. Don't know why it's happening.